# Get the count of Text, Numeric/Float, Blank and Nan values for each column in a Dataframe and extract using a filter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume the table below

| Index | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10.5 | 2.5 | nan |
| 1 |  | s |  |
| 2 | 2.9 | 3.2 | a |
| 3 | #VAL | nan | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | 5.6 | 4 |

Now what I'm trying to get is a summary dataframe which will give me a count of different datatypes/conditions as mentioned above

| Index | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Integer/Float | 3 | 3 | 2 |
| Blank | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Nan | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Text | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I come from Excel so in Excel conditioning it would be pretty much simple

**Integer/Float formula**: I would use ISNUMBER and create an array of True and False values and sum the true ones
**Blank**: I would simply use COUNTIF(Column, "")
**Text**: Similar to ISNUMBER I would use ISTEXT above.

I have tried searching this on Stack Overflow however the best I've gotten is

```
pd.DataFrame(df["Col1"].apply(type).value_counts())
```

This does not however give me the exact output.

I also wanted to check if it was possible to filter out the values basis the above condition and get the fitting cells.
e.g. df[Col1==ISTEXT]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom funstion for count each type separately:

```
def f(x):
    a = pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce').notna().sum()
    b = x.eq('').sum()
    c = x.isna().sum()
    d = len(x) - (a + b + c)
    return pd.Series([a,b,c,d], ['Integer/Float','Blank','Nan','Text'])

df = df.apply(f)
print (df)
               Col1  Col2  Col3
Integer/Float     3     3     2
Blank             1     0     1
Nan               0     1     1
Text              1     1     1
```